# UITextField not calling delegate method

Tags: objective-c, xcode, delegates, uitextfield, storyboard

I have a `DetailViewController`, which implementation file contains this code:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>

{
    __weak IBOutlet UITextField *nameField;
    __weak IBOutlet UITextField *numberField;
}

@end
```

In my storyboard, I have set the `ViewController`'s to `DetailViewController` and connected the delegate of both of my `UITextField`s to my `DetailViewController`. The implementation file of my `DetailViewController` contains this method to dismiss the keyboard when tapping somewhere other than the text field:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

This method is not called though, I have tested this using a breakpoint. What could be going wrong?

Comment: Did you put a log statement in there to see if it's called? This method is called when the user taps the return button, not when tapping somewhere other than the text field.

Comment: Put an `NSLog(@"DELEGATE => %@", nameField.delegate);` in your VDL to see if the delegate is actually being set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

rdelmar is correct, the code you have only gets triggered when the user hits the "return" key on the keyboard, not when they click outside of the keyboard.

To get the behavior you are looking for, I'd add a Tap Gesture Recognizer to the view behind your text field, then put `[nameField resignFirstResponder];` and `[numberField resignFirstResponder];` in the tap gesture recognizer's code.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that! I've added the Tap Gesture Recognizer, and now it works fine. :)

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use `_weak`? Remove it.

In your `.m` file do (in `viewDidLoad`):

```
[nameField setDelegate:self];
```

Same for the other textfield(s).

Comment: weak is fine for IBOutlets, and setting the delegate in IB should work fine also. In fact, the outlets are irrelevant to the problem at hand anyway -- the delegate should work even with no outlet names.

Comment: doing this all programmatically saves a lot of work and errors. you dont know what happens when building with the connections to the xib.. if you do all programatically you can easier spot the mistakes and stuff

Answer (score 0):

- I created a sample project
- added   to the viewcontroller
- added a textfield and connected its delegate
- write the code in viewcontroller

  ```
   (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
   {
      [textField resignFirstResponder];
      return YES; 
   }
  ```

it worked fine.Tried weak it also worked both as instance variable and property

So check if that you are reallocating it anywhere and also check its memory is same there using breakpoint